# radiobuttonlist selectedindexchanged event not firing every time

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the data bind code:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListItem> source = new List<ListItem>();
        source.Add(new ListItem("Remark A", "0"));
        source.Add(new ListItem("Remark B", "1"));
        source.Add(new ListItem("Remark C", "2"));

        rbnRemarks.DataSource = source;
        rbnRemarks.DataBind();
    }
    protected void rbnRemarks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshGrid();
    }
```

Here's the Markup page:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbnRemarks_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="rbnRemarks" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The problem is:

If I change the selected item to Remark B or Remark C the event is fired, but if I change the selected item back to Remark A, the event isn't fired and the Page_Init only triggers when I select Remark B or Remark C, why this happen??

Comment: I encountered something similar and it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291265/radio-button-stopped-working-after-conversion-from-asp-net-1-1-to-asp-net-3-5

Comment: @kermit Oh, thanks, that helps a lot, it solve my problem

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad it helped.